# Directional derivative of a function along a curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

i was trying to solve a problem of directional derivatives, but i'm confused.
Here is the problem.

The directional derivative of the function
$f:(x,y,z) \rightarrow \ xe^{(y^2 - z^2)}$ in $(1,2,-2)$ in the direction of the curve $r\rightarrow (t, 2cos(t-1), -2e^{(t-1)})$ is ...

I was trying to solve it, but i got stucked. Thank you so much.